# Support for TLSv1 in Python 3.10.5/Twisted 22.4.0

Tags: twisted, pyopenssl

I recently upgraded a server based on Python 3.8.6 to Python 3.10.5
The Twisted listener in it allows various devices to connect
Some of those devices only have TLSv1.
The server code specifically enables TLSv1/1.1/1.2/1.3 but only 1.2 and 1.3 work.
According to this issue https://bugs.python.org/issue43998 Python SSL no longer supports less than v1.2. But twisted uses pyOpenSSL, and I cannot find any documentation that states it only supports v1.2 and later.
Can anybody please supply some information on this.

Comment: There are a few ways to configure TLS in Twisted.  The answer might depend on which of these the server is using.

Comment: I am using this                 ctx_factory = ssl.CertificateOptions(key, crt, insecurelyLowerMinimumTo= ssl.TLSVersion.TLSv1_0)

Comment: 2022-08-10 10-42-09.094 [Host Listener] [MainThread] [DEBUG] SSL handshake: fatal: "internal error" at "b'error'"

Comment: Your `CertificateOptions` looks good to me.  My top guess was something to do with constructing the TLS context factory such that it disallowed the older versions of TLS.

Comment: I added a twisted issue, https://github.com/twisted/twisted/issues/11594 there is also a similar one, https://github.com/twisted/twisted/issues/11568